# Query Result is Null When Executed inside Controller's Constructor

Tags: laravel-9

I am facing a strange problem. It may be simple but I still can't figure this out.

The query result is null if I run it inside the controller's constructor (actually I am trying to set the few class properties for later access)

```
$voter = Voter::where('voting_center', $voting_center)->first();
```

Trying to access the properties like `$voter->name` results in

```
Attempt to read property "name" on null
```

The same query runs well inside other methods of the controller class.

Any idea why?

Comment: Even accessing the session results to null

Comment: It's the sequence or the way you are calling might be the problem, please share how are you trying to implement it and what's the end goal ? There are so many other aspects you might needs to look into, Traits or abstract class depends on what you want to achive.

Comment: @Vipertecpro It is a regular controller class. Just trying to set class properties with some query